# What is the relationship between requiretty in sudoers and daemon processes?

Tags: ruby, linux, passenger, daemon, sudoers

I wrote a Ruby script that runs as a daemon on a Linux server and periodically executes

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH "/usr/local/bin/passenger-status"
```

and logs the result to a text file. Everything works as expected.

My issues arise when  `requiretty` in sudoers is enabled.

Once  `requiretty` is enabled

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH "/usr/local/bin/passenger-status"
```

does not return anything when the script is running as a daemon. If the script is **not** run as a daemon, everything works as expected again.

What is the relationship between `requiretty` in sudoers and daemon processes? How do I properly enable `requiretty` in sudoers and get the expected behavior out of a daemon process?